# JSP filepath from servlet filter after deploying in Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I am trying to get the file paths of various JSP files inside my `webapp` folder after deploying the project in Tomcat. Here is what my directory structure looks like:

```
-project 
|-top
||-java
|||-com
||||-...
|||-filter
||||-MyFilter.java
||-webapp
|||-jsp
||||-MyJSP.jsp
```

So when the code hits my filter, what would the path be to `MyJSP.jsp` inside of the `doFilter()` method? I am trying to edit the contents of the file, so I need to be able to do `read` and `write` operations.

When I do `request.getServletPath()`, it shows the path: `/jsp/MyJSP.jsp`. However, when I try to read using the following code:

```
String str = "";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/jsp/MyJSP.jsp"));

while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str );
}

br.close();
```

I get a `FileNotFoundException`. What am I doing wrong? Is that not the actual path of the jsp file after it is deployed in Tomcat?

Also, I noticed some other questions saying put the files in the `WEB-INF` folder, however, there is nothing in that folder except for `web.xml` and I am not allowed to put anything in there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use `request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/jsp/MyJSP.jsp")`.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/jsp/MyJSP.jsp")));
```